# How to tranfer from one to another page if I will click on Yes or No button of message box in extjs?

Tags: extjs

When I will click on Yes button or No button of Messagebox, my page will transfer on another page.

```
Ext.Msg.show({
 title:'Register',
 msg: 'You are successfully registered. Would you like to continue?',
 buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL 
 });
```

Comment: If you are using a card layout,you will only need to navigate through the cards using setActiveitem(card), on click

Comment: No I am not using card layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Register',
    msg: 'You are successfully registered. Would you like to continue?',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
    callback: function(btn) {
        if (btn == 'yes') {
            window.location = 'newpage.html';
        }
    }
});
```